# smooth scrolling with sticky sub-navigation issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a web page with a fixed header and sticky sub-navigation with a smooth scroll on it. My problem is when clicking the sub-nav first link towards its target element, the sticky sub-navigation not showing up. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Here are the images. To clarify my question.
[image]
[image]

Here is my code.
https://codepen.io/christine-tine27/full/eYzMgjB

```js
// SMOOTH SCROLL
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(function () {
  $(".smoothScroll").click(function () {
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") ==
        this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $("[name=" + this.hash.slice(1) + "]");
      if (target.length) {
        $("html,body").animate(
          {
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200
          },
          1100
        );
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});


//  STICKY SUB NAV
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var height = $('.content-item.odd').outerHeight();
  if($(window).width() < "767"){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
           $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid #fff"});
      }
        else {
          $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
      }
  }else if($(window).width() < "1024") {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 550) {
           $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid #fff"});
      }
        else {
          $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
      }
  }else if($(window).width() > "2000") {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
           $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid #fff"});
      }
        else {
          $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
      }
  }else{
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 700) {
           $('.content-item.odd').addClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').css({"position":"fixed","width":"100%","top":"90px","border-top":"1px solid #fff"});
      }
        else {
          $('.content-item.odd').removeClass('fixed-header');
          $('.content-item.odd').removeAttr("style");
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body > header {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    *position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
    *background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
body > header .wrapper {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

body > header section {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    *left: 50px;
}
body > header nav {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
body > header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease;
}
body > header nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
body > header a {
    color: #FFF;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bgImg {
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.bgImg img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
}
.group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.group .half {
    width: calc(100% / 4);
    outline: none;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.half .img img {
    width: 100%;
}

.content-item.odd {
    background: #000;
    z-index: 3;
}

.prsub .content-wrap {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9ced1;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.prsub .group .half {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.half .img {
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
}

.the-content {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

h4.entry-title {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu {
    text-align: right;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}


.content-item.odd {
    background: #000;
    z-index: 3;
}
.menu {
    text-align: right;
}
.content-item.odd .wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
main {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
    margin-top: -4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
}

.content-item.odd .wrapper {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.prsub .content-wrap {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9ced1;
    padding-top: 0px;
}


main article h2 {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

main article ul, main article ol {
    color: #404041;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
main article section ul {
    font-size: 18px;
}

main article ul li, p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
}
.prsub h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.prsub article {
    padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <section>
         <a href="/" class="logo">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
         </a>
      </section>
      <nav>
         <div class="navx"></div>
         <ul class="ci-plugin">
            <li><a href="/home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/menu/"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/"><span>About </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/cook/"><span>Cook</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/"><span>Contact </span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/careers/"><span>Careers </span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
</header>

<section class="title">
   <div class="bgImg">
      <img src="https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page259/aria/assets/images/header-background.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</section>
<main id="main" class="prsub">
   <div class="content-container scroll">
      <div class="content">
         <div class="content-item odd">
            <div class="wrapper">
               <div class="the-content">
                  <h4 class="entry-title"><span> About Us</span></h4>
                  <div class="menu">
                     <ul >
                        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#intro">INTRO</a></li>
                        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="con-container">
            <div class="content-wrap">
               <article>
                  <section>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </section>
               </article>
            </div>
            <div class="content-wrap">
               <article>
                  <section id="intro">
                     <h2>
                        INTRO
                     </h2>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </section>
               </article>
            </div>
            <div class="content-wrap">
               <article>
                  <section id="services">
                     <h2>
                        SERVICES
                     </h2>
                     <h3>
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                     </h3>
                     <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                  </section>
               </article>
            </div>
            <div class="content-wrap">
               <article>
                  <section id="projects">
                     <h2>
                        PROJECTS
                     </h2>
                     <p>
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                     </p>
                  </section>
               </article>
            </div>
         </div>
        
        
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="group">
               <div class="half">
                  <div class="img"><img src="https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page259/aria/assets/images/intro-office.jpg"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="half">
                  <div class="img"><img src="https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page259/aria/assets/images/intro-office.jpg"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="half">
                  <div class="img"><img src="https://www.free-css.com/assets/files/free-css-templates/preview/page259/aria/assets/images/intro-office.jpg"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use `scroll-behavior: smooth` and `position:sticky`?  https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Comment: also, instead of using fixed scroll height check, use the offset for first target. Also, noticed that all checks are comparing `$(window).width()` with a string, should be a number.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Thanks.